# Avoid declaring lists before for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have following piece of code:

```
    results["date"] = []
    results["x"] = []
    results["y"] = []
    results["z"] = []
    results["t"] = []
    for pv in list(pvlist):
        results["date"].append(pv.date)
        results["x"].append(pv.x)
        results["y"].append(pv.y)
        results["z"].append(pv.z)
        results["t"].append(pv.t)
```

I want to loop over all my pv's and add the data to the output of my endpoint. Code looks very ugly like this.. Is there a better option to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
for pv in pvlist:  # pvlist is an iterable already
    for key in ("date", "x", "y", "z", "t"):
        results.setdefault(key, []).append(getattr(pv, key))
```

This should replace the entire snippet you posted. It replaces the repetitive code for each of the 5 keys/attributes by putting it in a loop and creates the empty lists lazily on demand when they are needed.

Comment: Thanks, there is a case where the getattr should use a different value than the key of the dict (so key is not the same). What would you do?

Comment: Loop over key/attr pairs: `for key, attr in (("datekey", "dateattr"), (...), ...)`. You might want to extract that key-attr pairs data structure into a variable to separate this "config" from the logic.